# How to boot my OS in Virtualbox?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

Here is my code:

```
section .text                   ;section declaration

                                ;we must export the entry point to the ELF linker or
    global  _start              ;loader. They conventionally recognize _start as their
                                      ;entry point. Use ld -e foo to override the default.

_start:

                                ;write our string to stdout

    mov     edx,len             ;third argument: message length
    mov     ecx,msg             ;second argument: pointer to message to write
    mov     ebx,1               ;first argument: file handle (stdout)
    mov     eax,4               ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80                ;call kernel

                                ;and exit

    mov     ebx,0               ;first syscall argument: exit code
    mov     eax,1               ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80                ;call kernel

section .data                   ;section declaration

msg db      "Hello, world!",0xa ;our dear string
len equ     $ - msg             ;length of our dear string
```

This is the hello world code for NASM
Then, I tried to compile it with nasm

```
nasm hello.nasm -o hello.bin
```

Then, i tried to convert it to an iso file

```
mkisofs -o hello.iso hello.bin
```

At last, i made a new virtual machine on virtual box with the CD Iso file hello.iso, but... The machine does not display my OS

why ?

I have: `FATAL: No bootable medium found. System halted.`

Comment: You likely need a boot signature (`dw 0xaa55`). You need to write code for 16-bit real mode since the boot sequence from an MBR starts your code that way (I'm assuming you are using legacy BIOS, but that is different for EFI). `int 0x80` is a Linux system call and isn't available at boot up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just a simply `Hello, World` in Netwide Assembly.

If you want to create a boot sector, you have to write a couple of things.

Please refer to this (awesome) [tutorial](http://os.phil-opp.com/multiboot-kernel.html), if you want to create an ISO image.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Linux Assembly`. In a way  you will understand, an operating system require special barebones programming (`x86`). Check out http://wiki.osdev.org for some help.

Also, I suggest you start with a floppy. CD-ROM is just hard for beginners.

Here's something to get you started.

```
BITS 16
org 0x7C00

; This is a comment

mov ah, 0eh ; Function<br>
mov al, 'A' ; Prints the letter A<br>
int 10h

times 510-($-$$) db 0<br>
dw 0xAA55
```

Command to compile.

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.img
```

Then, select Floppy controller for `Virtualbox` and start the virtual machine. You will see an `A`. You need BIOS interrupts to write an operating system. This is just the beginning.